# Evaluate a loaded hdf5 file from keras

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, hdf5

I would like to load a `hdf5` file and evaluate it. My question is, how can I access the data from the `hdf5` file so that I can evaluate this model? Can someone show me how to connect the loader to the metric?

**Loading:**

```
from keras.models import load_model
model = load_model('model.hdf5')
```

**Metric:**

```
# Mean Square Error (MSE)
def sparse_mean_square_error(sparse_ratings, user_embeddings, movie_embeddings):
    """
    Args:
      sparse_ratings: A SparseTensor rating matrix, of dense_shape [N, M]
      user_embeddings: A dense Tensor U of shape [N, k] where k is the embedding
        dimension, such that U_i is the embedding of user i.
      movie_embeddings: A dense Tensor V of shape [M, k] where k is the embedding
        dimension, such that V_j is the embedding of movie j.
    Returns:
      A scalar Tensor representing the MSE between the true ratings and the
        model's predictions.
    """
    predictions = tf.gather_nd(
        tf.matmul(user_embeddings, movie_embeddings, transpose_b=True),
        sparse_ratings.indices)
    loss = tf.losses.mean_squared_error(sparse_ratings.values, predictions)
    return loss
```

Comment: What do you mean by "_load and evaluate_"? The weights from your training session were saved previously with `model.save('model.hdf5')`. Calling `load_model('model.hdf5')` will load the weights from your trained model. You can continue with `model` as if this is a continuation of your training session (for testing or evaluation).

Comment: Load the previously saved model with `model = load_model('model.hdf5')`, and evaluate the model using 
`loss, acc = model.evaluate(test_images,  test_labels, verbose=2)
print('Restored model, accuracy: {:5.2f}%'.format(100*acc))`.                                                            For more details on the library you can find [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/keras/save_and_load#hdf5_format). Thanks